# Laravel Why I can access the method was not declared from Interface?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a problem like below:

I have an Interface name IBannerService

```
<?php
namespace App\Interfaces;

interface IBannerService
{
public function add($data);
public function list();
public function get($data);
public function delete($data);
}
```

and an instance name BannerService

```
class BannerService implements IBannerService
{

public function add($data)
{
    return true;
}

public function list()
{
    return true;
}

public function get($data)
{
    return true;
}

public function delete($data)
{
    return true;
}

public function test()
{
    print_r("aaaa");
    die();
}
}
```

finally I have a Controller name HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct(
    IBannerService $bannerService
    )
   {
     $this->bannerService = $bannerService;
   }
   public function index()
   {
    $listBanner = $this->bannerService->list();
    $this->bannerService->test();
   }

}
```

My configuration:

```
class DIServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'App\Interfaces\IBannerService',
        'App\Services\BannerService'
    );
}
```

In app.php:

```
'providers'=>[
    App\Providers\DIServiceProvider::class,
]
```

The code run well with $listBanner = true (just for testing).

The problem is:

Test Method was not declared in interface IBannerService but still go through and print out "aaa" the die.

Did I do something wrong?

Please suggest me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly normal functionality.

In the Laravel container you defined that when you ask for a `IBannerService` object, you want to get a `BannerService` class. And that is what you got. `BannerService` is an implementation of `IBannerService`, so no problem for the typehint.

A class is not limited to the functions defined by its interface so you can add as many other functions as you like. I wouldn't recommend it though, things like smart IDE's and phpstan would give you errors or warnings because to them, the variable is an implementation of `IBannerService` and this does not have a `test()` function.

If you really want to use more functions I would even recommend to use `BannerService` as the typehint. This way, static code analysis will still work.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jerodev! My question is Can I prevent Controller to call the test method in BannerService class? I just want to allow Controller use methods that only declared in Interface.

Comment: unless you make the function `private` or `protected`, you cannot prevent the controller from calling the function. If you need the `test()` function to be available somewhere else, you could consider making two different implementations of the `IBannerService` interface or move the test function somewhere else.